# name not define error when using a function but no error if not using a function

Tags: python

I have a code below that works well without error. I can just call the column name "label" without using the dataframe syntax of df['label'] in the where statement

[Working Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc2Ua.png)
However, when I used it inside a function as shown below, this same set of logic seems to be not working and I'm getting an error that the column "label" is not defined. Can I know why is this not working and how to make this work without using the df['label'] syntax ? Thanks

[Error in a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA98D.png)

Comment: Did you set the label variable somewhere previously in your program?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code and error message as text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ben See my answer, that error occurs because you didn't define or set the variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the enviroment of the funtion the variable `label` wasn't defined or isn't a  `global` variable. You will find helpful info about variables inside and outside a function in these links: [link 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/#:%7E:text=Global%20and%20Local%20Variables%20in%20Python,use%20them%20inside%20a%20function.&text=The%20variable%20s%20is%20defined,the%20%E2%80%9Cprint%20s%E2%80%9D%20statement.),[link 2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables).
You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def func(f):
      label = f.iloc[:, 0]   #get the first column
      for col in f.columns:
        vars()[col]=f[col]
      f = f.where(label== 'A')
      print(f)   

df = pd.DataFrame({'label':['A','B','A'], 'value':[1,2,3]}) 

func(df)

>>>         label  value
        0     A      1
        1     NaN    NaN
        2     A      3
```

If you are trying to only get the rows based on a specific condition, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def func(f):
  for col in f.columns:
    vars()[col]=f[col]
  f = f.loc[f['label'] == 'A']
  print(f)

df = pd.DataFrame({'label':['A','B','A'], 'value':[1,2,3]}) 
func(df)


>>>         label  value
        0     A      1
        2     A      3
```

You can checkout this way and another ways to select rows based on column values in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values).